# Combining Lists in python with common elements

Tags: python, list

I am generating lists with only '1' and '0' in them:

```
list_1 = [1,0,0,1,0,0]
list_2 = [1,0,1,0,1,0]
```

I am trying to combine them so that if a '1' appears in either list, it appears in the new list, and replaces any '0'

```
new_list = [1,0,1,1,1,0]
```

What would the code be?

Comment: What have you tried already? Please show your code and explain what is not working for you.

Comment: I thought of using a for loop to look at the items in both lists. if either list had a '1' then append a '1' else '0', but I am not sure of the loop code: for ex: for item in list_1 and item in list_2: .... but this results in an error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bitwise or `|` on a list comprehension and using a `zip` function:

```
>>> [x | y for x,y in zip(list_1, list_2)]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

If the lists don't have same length, use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.zip_longest) from `itertools` module:

```
>>> l1 = [1,1,1,0,0,1]
>>> l2 = [1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1]
>>> 
>>> [x | y for x,y in zip_longest(l1, l2, fillvalue=0)]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Another way, is to use [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.starmap) as well and remember in Python3, this yields a generator so you will have to convert it to `list` after that, this way:

```
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> from operator import or_ #bitwise or for the function passed to starmap
>>> list(starmap(or_, zip_longest(l1,l2, fillvalue=0)))
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could create your third list:

```
list_3 = [int(x or y) for x,y in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

I have a feeling there's a way better way to accomplish what you want, without using these lists. You can think of your lists as binary numbers:

```
num_1 = int("100100", 2)
num_2 = int("101010", 2)
num_3 = num_1 | num_2  # bitwise or
print(bin(num_3))  # prints '0b101110'
```

Comment: the first solution works. I am not sure how the second solution would receive the sequence since I am using a different routine to populate the lists.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the bitwise OR operation.  An OR of two bits will be 1 if either of the input bits are 1, and 0 if both are 0.

There are a variety of ways to do this in python over a list, but the simplest would just be a for loop.  Assuming the lists are the same length, this would work:

```
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(list_1)):
        new_list.append(list_1[i] | list_2[i]) # the '|' character means bitwise OR
```

Comment: Initially the lists would be the same length, but eventually, they would not. I think coding to the longest, (if  len(ls_1) >len(ls_2)...)  would be the solution.